# Negative voltage from positive output DC/DC

Tags: dc-dc-converter, inverter, high-voltage

my DC/DC ( http://www.ti.com/tool/PMP10077 ) has 200 V output on pins +HV and GND. Can I get negative output by simply swithcing the meaning of output pins -> I will use +HV as GND, and GND as +HV. I want to use it only as negative source, so the positive output is unwanted.

I used this idea with full wave rectifier -> when you switch the meaning of ouput pins you can get + or - waves, but only one of the option at once.

Is this possible with DC/DC?

If not, do you know about any DC/DC with negative output around -200 V/10 mA? Ideally ready to use system design. Input voltage around 19 V - 30 V.

//edit

-> input votlage info

-> added info about used DC/DC

Comment: What is the specific device you have?

Comment: This Texas Instruments design http://www.ti.com/tool/PMP10077

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical POL converter without galvanic separation.

As long as you prevent any further galvanic connections between your 200V circuit to the primary circuitry, you are fine.

After all, polarity is basicly mathematics.

But you probably will want connections between different parts of your circuitry. Then you will run into trouble with this POL-converter. You can look up, if there is a fully galvanically separated DC/DC converter with your spec, or a POL-converter with negative output.